# Getting the earliest date (duplicates due to several call ids and agents)

Tags: data, sql, descriptive-statistics, aggregation

I am trying to get the earliest call interaction, with only the agent that interacted at that call and the customer id. Using the following code, I still get duplicates:

```
select customer, agent, min(call)
from call_data;
```

I still get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem:

```
select distinct on (customer)
customer, agent, min(call)
from call_data;
```

I am using PostgreSQL.